# DECODE with multiple equal conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way to simplify this DECODE function? Note the variables are being compared to a NULL to validate if they are or not.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FNC_001
    (VAR_1 IN OUT VARCHAR, VAR_2 IN OUT VARCHAR, VAR_3 IN OUT VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR IS
 ERR_ERRFLG CHAR(1);
 BEGIN

    VAR_1 := TRIM(VAR_1);
    VAR_2 := TRIM(VAR_2);
    VAR_3 := TRIM(VAR_3);

    SELECT DECODE(NULL, VAR_1, 'Y', VAR_2, 'Y', VAR_3, 'Y', 'N') INTO ERR_ERRFLG
       FROM DUAL;

 RETURN ERR_ERRFLG;

 END;
```

Comment: Don't use `DECODE` unless you are already using SQL for another reason. It forces you to invoke the SQL engine which involves context switching. It's better to keep your conditional logic in straight PL/SQL unless you need table data and the conditional logic applies to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to return `null` if any of parameters is null, then one option is to use e.g.

```
return case when greatest(var_1, var_2, var_3) is null then 'Y' 
            else 'N'
       end;
```

Another might be

```
return case when var_1 is null or var_2 is null or var_3 is null then 'Y'
            else 'N'
       end;
```

but it is questionable if any of these is **simpler** than what you already have. Why don't you like it?

Comment: `greatest` is clever but isn't very self-documenting, as it would only make sense if folks know that any `null` operand will make the function result `null`.

Comment: Well, yes, @Paul. But - generally speaking - what you said is valid for *any* function or expression you might use. DECODE or COALESCE or CASE expression included. But I agree with what you said, it isn't self-documenting. Which is then a good opportunity for someone to check documentation :)

Comment: I do like your "GREATEST" option. I don't like DECODE because it seems repetitive to compare against the same value, & CASE is worse than that. Still, I do recognize it might not be that important of an issue.

Comment: OK, I'm glad you found it useful. Note that CASE is actually *preferred* when compared to DECODE because of readability, not to mention that some more complex things can't (or can, but with great difficulties) be implemented with DECODE, while - the same - can be easily achieved with DECODE. Basically, it is nice to have various options and then pick the one that suits your needs best.

Comment: Of course, I know these options have their own advantages, my preference over one is merely based on this very specific case. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

A few options to do it (compared to your DECODE() option):

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e     D a t a : 
    tbl (ID, COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) AS
        ( Select 1, 'A',  'B',  'C'  From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 'A',  null, 'C'  From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 'A',  'B',  null From Dual Union All
          Select 4, null, null, null From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--      S Q L :
Select  ID,
        Decode(Null, COL_1, 'Y', COL_2, 'Y', COL_3, 'Y', 'N') "DECODE_TEST",
        Case When InStr( Nvl(COL_1, '***') || Nvl(COL_2, '***') || Nvl(COL_3, '***'), '***' ) > 0
             Then 'Y'
        Else 'N'
        End "CASE_NVL_TEST",
        Case When COL_1 Is Null OR COL_2 Is Null OR COL_3 Is Null
             Then 'Y'
        Else 'N'
        End "CASE_OR_TEST",
        Case When Instr( Nvl(COL_1, '###') || Nvl(COL_2, '###') || Nvl(COL_3, '###'), '###' ) > 0
             Then 'Y'
        Else 'N'
        End "CASE_CONCAT_NVL_INSTR_TEST",
        Case When Greatest(COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) Is Null
             Then 'Y'
        Else 'N'
        End  "CASE_GREATEST_TEST",
        Case When Least(COL_1, COL_2, COL_3) Is Null
             Then 'Y'
        Else 'N'
        End  "CASE_LEAST_TEST"
From    tbl;
```

```sql
/*        R e s u l t :
ID  DECODE_TEST       CASE_NVL_TEST     CASE_OR_TEST      CASE_CONCAT_NVL_INSTR_TEST  CASE_GREATEST_TEST  CASE_LEAST_TEST
--  ----------------  ----------------  ---------------   --------------------------  ------------------  --------------------
1     N                 N                   N                   N                             N                   N
2     Y                 Y                   Y                   Y                             Y                   Y
3     Y                 Y                   Y                   Y                             Y                   Y
4     Y                 Y                   Y                   Y                             Y                   Y                   */
```